# How can I restrict the file types a user can upload to my form?

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, wtforms

I have a form which has a file upload field,I have also made a variable which contains a list of approved file types. I have also routed the uploads to go into a certain folder how do I use the following variable...

```
FILE_TYPES = set(['txt', 'doc', 'docx', 'odt', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'text', 'wks', 'wps', 'wpd'])
```

To incorporate into my function...

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash('Form successfully submitted')
    print "Form successfully submitted"
    filename = secure_filename(form.file_upload.data.filename)
    form.file_upload.data.save('uploads/' + filename)
    return redirect('home')
else:
    filename = None
    print(form.errors)  
    return render_template('index.html',
                            title='Application Form',
                            form=form,
                            filename=filename)
```

To make it so only these file types can be used?

Comment: I've tried to follow this guide but I'm having difficulty understanding the process of how to incorporate this into my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really simple example using your current function, you can improve upon this using examples from the [File Upload Patten](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/fileuploads/), but this minimally shows how to check if the submitted extension is in your `FILE_TYPES` set:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash('Form successfully submitted')
    print "Form successfully submitted"
    submit_name = form.file_upload.data.filename
    if '.' in submit_name and submit_name.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in FILE_TYPES:
        filename = secure_filename(submit_name)
        form.file_upload.data.save('uploads/' + filename)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        flash('File (%s) is not an accepted format' % submit_name)
        print submit_name
else:
    flash('form failed validation')
filename = None
print(form.errors)  
return render_template('index.html',
                        title='Application Form',
                        form=form,
                        filename=filename)
```